Why do most philosophers of religion accept or lean towards a libertarianism conception of free will?
When philosophers at large are surveyed, we observe this distribution (N=1758 [source]. 59.16% accept or lean towards compatibalism; 18.83% accept or lean towards libertarianism; 11.21% accept or lean towards no free will):

But when we filter by area of specialization to be philosophy of religion, we observe this distribution instead (N=141 [source]. 30.50% accept or lean towards compatibalism; 53.90% accept or lean towards libertarianism; 6.38% accept or lean towards no free will):

Why?

Willingness to believe?

Is a socio/anthropological question on philosophers a  question about philosophy?

My initial hypothesis was that there's a theism bias.
An earlier question noted that philosophy of religion has a theist majority.
If we look at your one link, we can see that's indeed the case:



r: 0.45
God: theism





Free will: libertarianism
Accept
Reject


Accept
167
134


Reject
147
1083



A mere 11% of atheists accept libertarianism, whereas 53% of theists accept libertarianism.
This may not fully account for the difference (it would seem pretty close to 54%, but 20% of philosophers of religion are atheists, which drags the number down). But it seems fair to say that this has the biggest effect, and the remaining difference may be more subject to noise.
Why is there a theism bias?
Well, theists commonly accept that there's something "outside the physical"* (whatever that means), that there's at least one consciousness (a god or gods) not subject to "physical" (typically deterministic, or random) forces.
* There's a strong correlation between theism and rejecting physicalism - 94% of theists reject physicalism (806/(53 + 806)).
It's also a fairly common theist belief that human consciousness persists after death.
So it's not much of a stretch for them to think human action is not subject to deterministic forces, i.e. libertarianism.
As for why 47% of theists (and 89% of atheists) reject libertarianism, one might suspect that they see too much evidence that makes them think our actions are subject to deterministic forces, in the form of neuroscience, psychology and evolution, or they find libertarianism to be incoherent. For theists, this may overwhelm their theism bias, whereas atheists don't have theism pushing in the other direction. But this is much more speculative and based on my own views on the matter. It might also be that non-libertarian theists reject libertarianism exactly because of their god belief, i.e. God determines every event (as per user80226's link).

Educated guess: because most philosophers of religion are theists (see Why do most philosophers of religion believe in God?), and the Free Will Theodicy is widely used by theists in response to the problem of evil, which arguably only makes sense under an indeterminist (libertarian) conception of free will:

With respect to the question of the justification of pain, cruelty, and other evils in relation to God, it is important to acknowledge the significant role played in theistic thought by appeal to the power of human free choice. We have seen above that many of the theodicies on offer rely on it. One prominent way to defend the goodness and other perfections of God in response to the evils of the world is to point out that, after all, God did not bring about the Rwandan genocide or the Holocaust or someone’s sexual assault. Instead, these were caused by human actions, which the theist may suggest were freely chosen by perpetrators. On the free will theodicy, God remains an absolutely perfect being even in light of the suffering in the world, because it is created beings who freely choose to harm each other (and non-human animals and the environment), and none of this is God’s direct doing. What goes wrong in our world is not the fault of God but rather the fault of the wrongdoers who use their power of free will to act badly. The free will theodicist holds that it is a great good that God gave us free will and allows us direct the course of our lives by way our own free choices (Swinburne 1998). The result of the gift of free will to the billions of people on the planet is a whole lot of bad consequences from evil choices, which God is justified in allowing because of the greater good of the gift of free will.
[...]
Another difficulty facing the free will theodicy is this: whereas some philosophers think that free will would be ruled out by the truth of causal determinism (the hypothesis that at each moment there is exactly one future, given the laws of nature and the events of the past), other free will theorists believe that we can act freely even if causal determinism is true. Arguably it is crucial that the free will appealed to by a free will theodicist must be indeterminist (libertarian) in nature. (For exploration of indeterminist accounts of free will, see Clarke 2003; Ekstrom 2000, 2019; Franklin 2018; Kane 1996; Mele 2006; O’Connor 2000.) The free will theodicist thus must maintain that all compatibilist accounts of the nature of free agency, including those provided by Frankfurt (1971), Watson (1975), Fischer (2012), Nelkin (2011), and Wolf (1990), among others, are implausible accounts. In citing the free will of created beings as the greater good that justifies God in permitting instances of evil or the facts about evil, the free will theodicist also needs to hold that causal determinism is, in fact, false and that we human beings do have libertarian free will. Without maintaining these positions, the free will theodicist lacks an explanation for the violence and cruelty in the world that shields God and preserves God’s goodness, since God could have established the initial conditions of the universe and decreed that deterministic natural laws govern all events, so that the events in the world unfolded to include none that are painful, harmful or wrong. God could have done this even in worlds in which he created free (in a compatibilist sense) rational beings.

If you don't believe in God, and instead accept or lean towards an alternative metaphysical view, such as physicalism, then there isn't really an issue involved in discarding libertarianism in favor of alternative conceptions of human volition.

But if you believe in God but not free will, it seems hideous and incoherent. (imho)

@ScottRowe I would agree with that intuition, although theological determinism is an actual thing and has supporters.

I wonder if there is a name for "taking a position because the apparent opposite position makes you run away screaming"?

Strange to hear that from the mouth (or fingers) of a staunch nondualist @ScottRowe. If there is only the One, how/where/what morality, responsibility, others?

@ScottRowe, "I will harden Pharaoh’s heart".

But aren't most theists compatibilists?

@curiousdannii Perhaps (do you have statistics on that?), but at least among theists who study philosophy of religion, compatibilism doesn't seem to be as popular.

@user80226 Yeah that could be the case, weird as it is.

Because we can only be morally responsible for our deeds if we can exercise free will.
No free will means no sin.
Clearly, most theists would find that objectionable.

Probably should be a separate question, but I don't see why "the universe is deterministic" and "intelligent beings should be held responsible for their actions" should be mutually exclusive beliefs.

If the universe is deterministic then you and your actions are deterministic too, since you are part of the universe. If you and your actions are deterministic then there is nothing you can do about that. It was already determined. It was always going to happen that way. How can you be held responsible for that?

Say in the future AI becomes conscious. You would argue that, regardless of how complex their emergent behavior is, since AI is deterministic it necessarily cannot be held responsible for its actions?

Not in a moral sense, no. For practical purposes you can apply responsibility in the sense of consequences so the AI can improve/learn.  I advocate the same for people. I think retributive punishment is wrong.

If this is true I think the relevant concept of “moral” here is deeply deficient. The point of morality is normativity, not choice - you may have no choice in the matter but a harm caused by an action taken is still clearly wrong.

@SofieSelnes   Just like the rain is wrong. The fact that I get wet is clearly wrong..

@Philomath we’re talking about actions here. An agent doesn’t need to be free to be a moral cause for an outcome - they just need reasons and intentions.

I don't see how anybody who is not free is anything else but a force of nature.

@Philomath thus speaks the slave driver

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Mathematically, what we should expect is randomness, not complex order.  The fact there is complex order can lead one to believe in a supreme intelligence organizing the cosmos.  However, if the supreme intelligence itself operates according to pure mathematics, i.e. determinism, then we arrive back at the original problem, which is the supreme intelligence should itself just generate randomness, not complex order.  The only way out of this mess is to posit some causal power beyond determinism, i.e. libertarian free will.  In which case, belief in theism entails belief in libertarian free will.

I think this is importantly different, and critically in error, to the above answers. We might say that theism requires free will, but to say free will implies theism is just false - non-theistic dualism is entirely plausible as an option. (I’m compatibilist so it’s purely hypothetical but god/s don’t need to enter the discussion at all)

The premise of this answer is wrong. The fact that complex behavior can emerge from randomness and simple rules is well-known, and an active area of study. Ex. Conway's Game of Life can perform arbitrary computations; and modern LLMs, which are no more than fancy predictive text, have arguably passed the Turing Test.

@SofieSelnes good catch, fixed.

@BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft the game of life only exhibits complex order when humans design mechanisms, like Turing machines.  GoL populated with random noise just produces trivial "ash" objects.  Similarly with LLMs.  The algorithm for LLMs is trivial, all the magic is from the training data produced by human intelligence.  When LLMs are trained on their own output, this results in "model collapse".
